# one way (unique) relationship on many-to-many table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, relationship

Hey there I have a many to many table which displays a connection between 2 users in **postgresql**. The table looks like that:

```
CREATE TABLE message_connection (
    mc_id serial primary key,
    mc_opener int NOT NULL,
    mc_partner int NOT NULL,
    unique (mc_opener, mc_partner)
)
```

However I **only want to allow one relationship between two users**, because it contains redundant information.

In this example (1,2) is already in there, so I don't want (2,1).

```
+---------+-------------+--------------+
| "MC_ID" | "MC_OPENER" | "MC_PARTNER" |
+---------+-------------+--------------+
|         |             |              |
| 1       | 1           | 2            |
|         |             |              |
| 6       | 1           | 4            |
|         |             |              |
| 7       | 2           | 4            |
|         |             |              |
| 8       | 2           | 1   <-- I dont' want to allow that
+---------+-------------+--------------+
```

How can I do that in SQL? 
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean (2,1) shouldn't be accepted since (1,2) is already in the table?

Comment: yes exactly! @jarlh